# Tensorflow: Truncating a Tensor Seems to Have No Effect

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the `tf.data.Dataset` API and am trying to truncate a bunch of tensors to length 100.  Here's what my `dataset` looks like:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'reviews': x}, y))
```

My reviews are just movie reviews (strings), so I perform some preprocessing and map that function on my dataset:

```
def preprocess(x, y):
    # split on whitespace
    x['reviews'] = tf.string_split([x['reviews']])
    # turn into integers
    x['reviews'], y = data_table.lookup(x['reviews']), labels_table.lookup(y)
    x['reviews'] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(x['reviews'])
    # truncate at length 100
    x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][:100]
    x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][0]
    x['reviews'] = tf.pad(x['reviews'],
           paddings=[[100 - tf.shape(x['reviews'])[0], 0]],
           mode='CONSTANT',
           name='pad_input',
           constant_values=0)
    return x, y

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
```

However, my code fails with:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Paddings must be non-negative: -140 0
```

On an input of length 240. So, it seems like my padding step calculates 100 - 240 = -140 and I get this error.

Here's my question: how is this possible, given that I truncate to length 100 with:

```
x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][:100]
```

It seems clear that this line isn't having any effect, so I'm trying to understand why. The docs are very clear that this is acceptable syntactic sugar for `tf.slice`:

```
Note that tf.Tensor.getitem is typically a more pythonic way to 

perform slices, as it allows you to write foo[3:7, :-2] instead of 

tf.slice(foo, [3, 0], [4, foo.get_shape()[1]-2]).
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You have this line inbetween truncating and padding: `x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][0]`. So after truncating whatever-it-is to 100 elements, you then pick only the first (0th) element from that... which could be any size for all we know, at least it hasn't been truncated.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thanks for the comment!  I only included that line because my `x['reviews']` was a 2-d tensor without it :( If I take out `x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][0]`, then I get an error with padding: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'pad_input' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [?,?], [1,2].` . Thoughts?  Seems to point to a 2-d tensor (which is why I did `x['reviews'] = x['reviews'][0]` to start with)

Comment: You should review `tf.pad` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)) and correct the shape of the `paddings` argument. It's hard to say more because we don't know what your data looks like, what the dimensions represent etc.